# Excel VBA 2010 Looking up for a value in a random sized multidimentional array

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to look up for certain values in an multidimensional array.

Say for an example: There is an array with 4 columns and say 500 or some number of rows that changes every time(the size of the array is dynamic and varies from time to time, so basically a loop with fixed number like i = 1 to 500 and j = 1 to 4 won't work) .

Now I design an Userform and feed a value. Is there a function like filter() that can look up for this value in this multi-dimentional array? Is there any other way to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. define the range
2. use the **.Find** method to locate the data:

Here is an example for columns **A** through **D** for an unknown number of rows.

```
Sub qwerty()
   Dim rng As Range, N As Long
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Set rng = Range("A1:D" & N)
   addy = rng.Find(What:="happiness", After:=rng(1)).Address
   MsgBox addy
End Sub
```